# Why am I getting SIGTERM error after every simulator run?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, ios-simulator

Every time I run the simulator, SIGTERM appears after doing so. It doesn't affect my project because I can still work and run sim but it's very annoying and I think it is a bug. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this before too on a simulated device. Here's some solutions to try that worked for me!

1. Product > Clean
2. Uninstall/delete your apps from your devices manually and compile again.
3. In the iOS Simulator, iOS Simulator > "Reset Content and Settings".
4. Delete everything in your "Derived Data" for the project.
5. Lastly, the classic restart Xcode and/or restart your machine.